# Elliptic function degree

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

If $f$ is an elliptic function (wrt a given lattice), and $R=p/q$ a rational function, then is there a formula allowing to compute the degree of the elliptic function $R(f)$ in Terms of the degree of $f$ and the polynomial degrees of $p$ and $q$?

I would like to use this to prove that if $f$ is an elliptic function such that $\wp$ and $\wp'$ can be rationally expressed through $f$, then $f$ must have degree $1$ (i.e. cannot exist).

Comment: indeed @AlonsoDelfín

Comment: I have a question. Do you want to prove that there is no $f$ such that $$ f=R_1(\wp) \ \text{ and } \  f=R_2(\wp') $$ or such that $$ \wp=R_1(f) \ \text{ and } \  \wp'=R_2(f) ?$$ I think I've come up with something for both cases, not sure yet on my argument for the second one though

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín: the second one is intended

Comment: $\deg (R\circ f) = \operatorname{ord} R \cdot \deg f$, where the order of a rational function is $\operatorname{ord} \frac{p}{q} = \max \{\deg p, \deg q\}$ if $p$ and $q$ are coprime.